# Vue.js: How to load a template asynchronously after I retrive data from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

So, I'm trying to retrieve the links for some pdfs from my firebase storage. When I get the link I want to bind them to certain lists. The problem is the template is loaded before the links are fetched so the lists' href attribute remains null.I'm using Vuetify too.

Here is my template

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap v-if="count > 0">
    <v-flex v-for="n in count" :key="n">
      <v-card:href="link[n-1]" target="_blank">
        <v-icon>mdi-file-pdf</v-icon>
        <span>Module {{n}}</span>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
import firebaseApp from "@/firebase/init.js";
var storage = firebaseApp.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
export default {
  name: "Dashboard",

  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      count: null,
      link: [],
      loading: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getFile() {
      this.link = [];
      this.loading = true;
      var listRef = storageRef.child(`folder_name${this.id}`);

      listRef.listAll().then(res => {
        this.count = res.items.length;
        for (let i = 1; i <= this.count; i++) {
          var starsRef = storageRef.child(`folder_name${this.id}/file_name${i}.pdf`);
          starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            this.link[i - 1] = url;
          });
        }
        this.loading = false;
      });
    },
    updateId() {
      this.id = this.$route.params.id;
      this.getFile();
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getFile();
  },

  watch: {
    $route: "updateId"
  }
};
</script>
```

The link array will eventually store all the links. But it would not be bound to the span tag
How do I get over this without using vuex?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code try to see if `count` and `link` are actually updated with console.log or the Vue devtools

Comment: Hey @Pierre, only the count gets updated and I'm able to see all the span tags. But the `link array is not getting updated before the template is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDownloadURL()` method is asynchronous and returns a Promise. Since you want to execute this method in parallel for all the files in `storageRef.child('folder_name${this.id}')` you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait that all the asynchronous operations are completed before updating the `link` array.

The following, using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a `for` loop, should do the trick (untested):

```
 listRef.listAll()
 .then(res => {
    const promises = [];
    res.items.forEach(itemRef => {    //items is an array of Reference
         promises.push(itemRef.getDownloadURL());
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
 .then(urls => {
   this.link = urls;
 });
```

Then, in your component you would do:

```
  <v-layout row wrap v-if="count > 0">
    <v-flex v-for="(item, index) in link">
      <v-card :href="item" target="_blank">
        <v-icon>mdi-file-pdf</v-icon>
        <span>Module {{index + 1}}</span>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```